# Can I store entire label to sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all I would like to access label and set the text for that label in another form, so I tried as follows

```
function ShowNewPage() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("total", $('#<%= lblHidden %>'));
        modalWin.ShowURL('test.html', 300, 400, 'Second From', null, callbackFunctionArray);
    }
```

But I am not able to access the label it in another form when I use the following `sessionStorage.getItem("total")` so can some one help me

Comment: As far is I remember storage only accepts dom strings as key/value. so try to set it as string value

Answer (score 2):

Web storage only stores strings so you can't store a jQuery object or dom element directly

Just store the selector that references that object and you can wrap the stored selector in `$()` when you need to use it

```
sessionStorage.setItem("total", '#<%= lblHidden %>');
```

Then to use:

```
var selector = sessionStorage.getItem("total");
alert($(selector).attr('id'));
```

Comment: Can I set value to that label?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to as `label`. If needed you can store an object literal as json and have whatever properties you need in that object

Comment: I need to change the label text in another form based on few calculations

Comment: Something like: `var data =JSON.stringify({selector:  '#<%= lblHidden %>', value: 456}) ; sessionStorage.setItem("total", data);` .. then use JSON.parse when you retrieve it

Comment: And I'm not clear on what you are trying to do. I am showing you how to stringify a more complex object to be able to store that within one storage key